# Should we use 'include' in use case diagrams for use cases belong to different actors

Tags: use-case

I have a requirement that is a user of the system can make a complaint about an organization and then the admin can blacklist that organization. Do I have to include the use case "Make complaints"(of user) to the use case blacklist(of admin). Please help me with this matter.

Comment: I don't understand your 2nd sentence

Comment: @Mibac My idea is,  "complaining an organization by a user" should have been occurred for the use case blacklisting and organization to be done. I am afraid do I have to use an include for those two use cases.

Comment: This just sounds like two independent stories: "A user can complain so that the admin is aware of an issue with an organization," and "An admin can blacklist an organization so that that organization can no longer be used."

Comment: @Derek Elkins. Yes, but my problem is "An admin should first be aware about an issue to initiate blacklisting process"

Comment: @user3628865 So? The admin doesn't need to be made aware via your system. You're mixing together policy and mechanism. A use-case diagram is not a business process diagram. If you want a process flow diagram, use one. In your use-case diagram, presumably both the user and the admin will be involved with the complaint, but only the admin will be involved with the blacklisting. That there is a process-flow connection between these actions is not formally captured by the use-case diagram.

Answer (score 2):

A use-case diagram is not meant to be a comprehensive view of the system and its behavior.  It merely provides a high-level, actor-oriented, simplified view of possible interactions with the system so as to be accessible and not overwhelming.  Other artifacts supported by other notations can be used to capture other aspects of the system, the same aspects from a different perspective, or to provide a more detailed description of the interactions e.g. [swimlane diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swim_lane), [Activity Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram), or [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation).

In your particular case, I'm assuming that the Admin is *capable* of blacklisting any organization at any time.  It is merely a *policy* that a complaint should be filed first.  If this policy is enforced by mechanism (making the assumption false), for example, the "Blacklist" button is not enabled unless there is a complaint filed against the organization, then that will be a detail of the blacklisting use-case but probably doesn't warrant being formally captured in a use-case diagram (perhaps a comment will be added). If a policy is not enforced by the system, then it's simply not part of the system and shouldn't be included in the system description. It is part of the business process and may be included in a business process diagram of which the system is but a part. (Of course, you can make a *business* use-case diagram as opposed to a *system* use-case diagram, at which point business processes not captured by/involving the system are relevant.)

If you are dead-set on including this relationship in your system use-case diagram, then it's clear that the `extends` relation makes more sense than the `included by` relation as apparently the blacklisting is an optional additional behavior. (If it isn't, why is an admin involved at all?) Alternatively, you could simply have the user also associated with the Blacklist use-case, though that will obviously not indicate any necessary connection with the Complains use-case. However, most examples of use-case diagrams I've seen have implicit but completely uncaptured constraints between use-cases e.g. mutual exclusion and ordering constraints.

Comment: I don't think that an [`extends` relationship](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/useCaseReuse.htm#Extend) is at all appropriate. If Use Case A extends Use Case B, that means that at some point in the flow of executing Use Case A, Use Case B is triggered. In this example, the user completes the "make complaint" use case and is done. A different actor executes the "blacklist organization" use case. There's no way to accurately depict this relationship in a standard UML use case diagram. Nearly everything, except the last sentence, of the last paragraph is misleading.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I agree hence the first two paragraphs of my answer and the highly conditional wording of the final paragraph, but I would say that *between* `extends` and `included by`, any argument you could make against `extends` applies even more strongly against `included by`. That said, that one choice is not as bad as another doesn't make it a good choice. Though I could make it more clear that my recommendation is to omit it from the use-case diagram altogether, though it sounds like the OP wants a different tool entirely than a use-case diagram. I'm also not a fan of use-case diagrams.

Comment: I would love to up-vote this answer, but both `extends` and `includes` make no sense. I feel that suggesting either as a valid option (even indicating that they are both poor options) makes this answer incorrect. The correct answers are to use a different diagram type and/or to represent your use cases in a different manner that allows for this information to be documented clearly. Misusing the language of a use case diagram is the wrong answer - it's confusing to readers and doesn't actually capture the design of the system.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you should. A use case diagram does not have a notion of a "requires" relation between two use cases (only "includes" and "extends" are part of the formal definition).

If I had to make a use case diagram, I would list them as separate use cases with different actors. This says that a user is able to execute the "Make Complaints" use case and an admin is able to execute the "Blacklist Organization" use case.

However, this is one of the reasons why I'm not a fan of use case diagrams. There are many things that can't be expressed well in the confines of a use case diagram. I prefer textual or tabular representations of use cases. Using a textual or tabular method, you can capture preconditions for a use case to be executed (such as a user having executed the Make Complaints use case before an admin is able to execute the Blacklist Organization use case).